# Ionic Tinder cards add new card functionality breaks swipe animation when card added when card view is not the active view

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

Adding new cards to the card array while not in the tinder card view breaks the transition out animation when we come to swipe that card. I have made a codepen http://codepen.io/antonfire/pen/xwrjPx to show this with add card buttons on the card view and another view. Normally the card smoothly swipes out, but in the case of cards added off view, the animation is incorrect. I am adding the cards using the following code.

```
  var cardTypes = [
    { image: 'http://api.randomuser.me/portraits/women/31.jpg' },
    { image: 'http://api.randomuser.me/portraits/women/32.jpg' },
    { image: 'http://api.randomuser.me/portraits/women/33.jpg' },
    { image: 'http://api.randomuser.me/portraits/women/34.jpg' },
    { image: 'http://api.randomuser.me/portraits/women/35.jpg' },
    { image: 'http://api.randomuser.me/portraits/women/36.jpg' },
    { image: 'http://api.randomuser.me/portraits/women/37.jpg' },
  ];

  $scope.cards = Array.prototype.slice.call(cardTypes, 0);

  $scope.cardDestroyed = function(index) {
    $scope.cards.splice(index, 1);
  };

  $rootScope.addCard = function() {
    var newCard = cardTypes[Math.floor(Math.random() * cardTypes.length)];
    newCard.id = Math.random();
    $scope.cards.push(angular.extend({}, newCard));
  }
```

This code works when we are adding a card while in the same view as the card but if we add the card from another view controller it doesn't work.

Any help much appreciated thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking at this I identified the issue was arising from the following lines of code in the tinder cards .js:

```
  this.parentWidth = this.el.parentNode.offsetWidth;
  this.width = this.el.offsetWidth;
```

When a new card is added while in the view containing the Tinder cards directive the card width and parent element can be determined by javascript using `offsetWidth`. If the card is added while the view containing the directive is not the current view javascript cannot calculate `offsetWidth` as it is not currently rendered in the viewport. As such I used the following workaround, replace the previous code with the following:

```
  this.parentWidth = window.innerWidth;
  this.width = 300;
```

This is a bit of a hack as `width` will need to match `width` in tinder cards CSS and `parentWidth` will need to be adjusted to take account of any other elements the cards directive sits within.